# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el directorio de trabajo de docker?

Tags: docker

Por defecto docker guarda los contenedores y las imágenes en /var/lib/docker, necesito colocarlo en otro punto de montaje.

Answer (score 2):

Se debe modificar el archivo `daemon.json` en  `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

agregando:

```
{
     "graph":"/mipath/dockerhome"
}
```

Más información en:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#linux-configuration-file